# Count unique values in Excel worksheet column

Tags: excel, counter, vba

This is new to me. I'm trying to count how many different values I have in a column on my ws, the problem is that the same value repeats many times and I only want to count it once. Some friends tried to help me with the code but I'm kind of lost right now for example I don't know why I'm using a function or why do I have to put the "Option Explicit" on top of it, any ideas are welcome.

```
Option Explicit    

Function CountUnique(datarange As Range)
Dim datarange
Dim CheckCell
Dim Counter As Double
Counter = 0

For Each CheckCell In datarange.Cells
    Counter = Counter + (1 / (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(datarange, CheckCell.Value)))
Next

CountUnique = Counter

End Function
```

Comment: You can achieve that by creating pivot table. If you are sure VBA the only way, then take a look at solutions like SQL Distinct with aggregate function via ADODB (workbook should be saved on a drive), or using dictionary within loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option Explicit when stated, you must explicitly declare all variables used. By using Dim and Redim, this allows your code to be more easily debugged imo.

As for why it is a function, that is up to the coder. What you are trying to do could have been done also in a sub macro as well. A function is called upon by giving it variables. In larger programs, this can organize things drastically.

Here is an example of a sub calling on the function.

```
Option Explicit

Function CountUnique(datarange As Range)
Dim CheckCell
Dim Counter As Double
Counter = 0

For Each CheckCell In datarange.Cells
    Counter = Counter + (1 / (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(datarange, CheckCell.Value)))
Next

CountUnique = Counter
Msgbox Counter
End Function
```

By running test() it will call on the function

```
 Sub test()
    Dim rag As Range
    Set rag = Range("A1:A23")
    Call CountUnique(rag)
    End Sub
```

Comment: It worked, Just had to change a few things. like set a range and choose a cell to print the result instead of showing a msg. Thanks a lot. Now i'm trying to make it faster but I'm afraid I won't be able to do much.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Option Explicit

Function CountUnique(datarange As Range) As Long
    Dim c As Collection, r As Range
    Set c = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each r In datarange
            c.Add r.Value, CStr(r.Value)
        Next r
    On Error GoTo 0
    CountUnique = c.Count
End Function
```

[image]